# How do I define a global variable as 'far' in assembly?

Tags: pointers, assembly, global-variables

I know in c it's as easy as

```
far int var;
```

but how would I do this in assembly?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special - global variables can be accessed from anywhere in assembly. What O/S, CPU, are you targeting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved with compile options for my hardware

Answer (score 0):

There is no far variable. There is a far pointer type. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That sounds correct from what I've read. I just still can't figure out how to translate the c statement:
    far int var;
into an assembly statement

Comment: It depends on what hardware you have. On a 286 `far` meant that the variable was in a different segment.

Comment: -S is your friend.  Compile your C code to assembler and see what it does.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, it seems using different segments. Found for ARM: far uses HDATA and near uses NDATA segments.